# Why is the image not aligning as planned on small mobile screen?

Tags: html, css

```css
body{
  overflow-x:hidden;
  overflow-y:hidden;
    }
```

```html
 <a href="#"> <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x800?text=1"></a>
```

However I want the center of the image to be visible on mobile devices, as shown here: [image]

It is not possible to change the image dimensions and code format in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular situation you can use the CSS below to center the image (i.e. the link). But you'll have more elements than that, I suppose...

Note: This way the image will also center if its smaller than the screen.

```css
body{
  overflow-x:hidden;
  overflow-y:hidden;
    }
a {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
```

```html
<a href="#"> <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x800?text=1"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `max-width: 100%;` to the image and it will scale down to smaller viewports.

```css
body {
  overflow-x:hidden;
  overflow-y:hidden;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
 <a href="#"> <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x800?text=1"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your whole document consist of only one image, and you want it to be contained to the window, you could do it like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/5yvtz7nt/

Basically do

```
html
{
    height: 100%;
}
body
{
    margin: 0; /* browser have a default margin on body sometimes */
    height: 100%;
}
a
{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
img
{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: your earlier answer in js fiddle was great.Why did you edit it?

Comment: I thought this edit was more what you were looking for. I can rollback that edit, if you think that's more appropriate?